# How to find the final form of $\sum_{j=0}^{N} {N\choose j} \left(\frac{c}{N}\right)^j\left(\frac{N-c}{N}\right)^{N-j}$?

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics, summation

I am wondering what the final form of:

$$
\sum_{j=0}^{N} {N\choose j} \left(\frac{c}{N}\right)^j\left(\frac{N-c}{N}\right)^{N-j}
$$
where $c\in \mathbb{N}$ here is a constant smaller than $N$.

would be. Is there an easy way to do this? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an instance of the binomial theorem:

$$\sum_{j=0}^N\binom{N}j\left(\frac{c}N\right)^j\left(\frac{N-c}N\right)^{N-j}=\sum_{j=0}^N\binom{N}j\left(\frac{c}N\right)^j\left(1-\frac{c}N\right)^{N-j}=\left(\frac{c}N+\left(1-\frac{c}N\right)\right)^N=1\;.$$

**Added in response to a comment:** We can use the identity $j\binom{N}j=N\binom{N-1}{j-1}$ to write

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{j=0}^Nj\binom{N}j\left(\frac{c}N\right)^j\left(\frac{N-c}N\right)^{N-j}&=N\sum_{j=0}^N\binom{N-1}{j-1}\left(\frac{c}N\right)^j\left(\frac{N-c}N\right)^{N-j}\\
&=N\sum_{j=0}^{N-1}\binom{N-1}j\left(\frac{c}N\right)^{j+1}\left(\frac{N-c}N\right)^{N-1-j}\\
&=N\cdot\frac{c}N\sum_{j=0}^{N-1}\binom{N-1}j\left(\frac{c}N\right)^j\left(\frac{N-c}N\right)^{N-1-j}\\
&=c\left(\frac{c}N+\frac{N-c}N\right)^N\\
&=c\;.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: If instead we have $\sum_{j=0}^Nj \binom{N}j\left(\frac{c}N\right)^j\left(\frac{N-c}N\right)^{N-j}$, is there an easy way to get the form from what you have? Thanks!

Comment: @user321627: It takes a little more work, but we can still get a simple closed form.